# Decrypt File Uploaded In Zend Framwork While Download

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-io, zend-form-element, zend-file

I am making a zend project that has a file upload functionality and the client wanted to encrypt and upload the files without their extension. I did that perfectly by using the following code :

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http ();
$salt = $upload->getHash('md5', 'file_name');
$upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../uploads/presentations/'.$salt));
$upload->addFilter('Encrypt', array('adapter' => 'mcrypt', 'key' => $constants->encryption_key));
$upload->receive ();
```

This is working fine now I'm just downloading the file with the following code

```
$filename = 'example_presentation_file.ppt'; //original name in db. by the way this coming from database
$hash = '85be69db87a43265a44be1482cc6d819'; //changed file name when uploaded with this
$mime = 'application/octet-stream';
$file_path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../uploads/presentations/'.$hash;
header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
$size = filesize($file_path);

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range = intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end = $size-1;
    }
    else {
        $range_end = intval($range_end);
    }
    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
}
else {
    $new_length = $size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
}
@ob_end_clean();
$speed = false;
$chunksize = ($speed?($speed * 1024):(1024 * 1024)) ;
$bytes_send = 0;
$buffer = "";
if ($file = fopen($file_path, 'r')) {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        fseek($file, $range);
    }
    while(!feof($file) && (!connection_aborted()) && ($bytes_send<$new_length)) {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer);
        flush();
        if($speed) {    
            if($type!=2) sleep(1);
        }
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

This code is working very fine and downloading the file but when I open that file in powerpoint, it doesn't open it and displays an error.

The point is that, If i disable the file encryption, I opens very good but it is necessary. I just wanted to know that how to decrypt the file in run time (just when user downloads it not forever).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following workflow:

1. Temporary decrypt the encrypted file and save it somewhere
2. Send **this** decrypted file to the client
3. Remove decrypted file from the file system

Example:

```
<?php

/* ... */

$options = array(
'adapter' => 'mcrypt', 
'key'     =>  $constants->encryption_key);


$decrypt = new Zend_Filter_File_Decrypt($options);

// temp. decrypt file and save it on the disc
$decrypted_file_path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../uploads/presentations/'. $filename;
$decrypt->setFilename($decrypted_file_path);

// encrypted file location
$decrypt->filter($file_path);

/* your code: Send $decrypted_file_path to the client */

// remove decrypted file
unlink($decrypted_file_path);
```

Comment: Exactly as I thought. Is there any other way to do that.  By the way thanks for that.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com, I doubt there is another viable solution